# Cocos2d side scrolling game best way to implement it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I was wondering if its better to add sprite by sprite(spritesheets) for the each level of the game? or is it better to add segment by segment for the levels in the game?

The thing is that i want to be able to have animated objects in my game.. like moving platforms, falling platforms, part of the wall that can smash your player, but the thing is the level has an end. its not an endless game like jetpack joyride... it has end per level like Badland

example:

[Badland Side-Scrolling Action Adventure Game](http://www.badlandgame.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Hello I would use SpriteHelper and LevelHelper. I have learned that they are very helpful in making game with levels. With these applications, you can plan out your level sprite by sprite. They are cheap. I know on the Mac App Store, LevelHelper is $24.99 and SpriteHelper is $16.99. SpriteHelper is a sprite packer and LevelHelper allows you to lay out your game world/level. Here are the websites for both. 
LevelHelper- http://www.gamedevhelper.com/levelhelper/

SpriteHelper-  http://www.gamedevhelper.com/spritehelper/

Ray Wenderlich has great tutorials on those two apps.

Here is the link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/28713/how-to-make-a-game-like-jetpack-joyride-using-latest-levelhelper-spritehelper-cocos2d-edition-part-1

This tutorial uses the example of "a game like Jetpack Joyride." I know that this is not the game you want to learn how to make but it gives you great insight about how to use LevelHelper and SpriteHelper. The links for the apps also have guides on how to use the two apps.

Hope this helped and Good Luck!